# Fortran: inexact value read from a text file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a short Fortran program that reads data into a table:

```
  open (1, file="input1.txt", status="old", action="read", form="formatted")
  do line = 1,10000
    read(1,*) in1(line)
  end do
  close(1)
  print *, in1(100)
```

The file `input1.txt` has 10000 real numbers in one column, one below the other.
The problem is that within the text file the number under row 100 is `0.401989363445`. However, the program above prints: `0.401989371`. This is a different value... and it does not seem as a rounding issue... What is going on?

The program is compiled with `gfortran`, if that makes a difference...

Comment: What is the data type of the variable read (real or double precision or ...). Looks like a typical form of the limitation of a real (32 bit) variable.